# Trying to replace some text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using notepad++ to find and replace some variables but also add some items.

I need

```
<date>20140427</date>
```

replaced with

```
<previously-shown start="2014-04-27"></previously-shown>
```

So far I have

Find what:

```
<date>\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}</date>
```

replace with:

```
{<previously-shown start="} + \3-\2-\1"></previously-shown>
```

Comment: Add groups to the pattern - `<date>(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})</date>` and replace with `<previously-shown start="$1-$2-$3"></previously-shown>`

Comment: You did not describe the problem -- only what you did.  I notice that you have not added any matching groups, so `\3` etc refer to nothing.  To create a matching group, surround it with parentheses.

Comment: Solved. I had to create groups.
<date>(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})</date>
<previously-shown start="$1-$2-$3"></previously-shown>

Answer (score 0):

Add [**capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to the pattern and change the order of the backreferences in the replacement:

**Find What**: `<date>(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})</date>`
**Replace With**: `<previously-shown start="$1-$2-$3"></previously-shown>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tNxFpv/1).

[image]